# Automating Faxing using RFCOMAPI.DLL

Tags: rightfax

I am attempting to automate faxing using the Rightfax API RFCOMAPI.DLL.  I have followed the instructions detail by detail and cannot seem to get this working.

RightFax 10.6 is installed on the machine.   I have copied the rfcomapi.dll, rfwin32.dll, rfi32rpc.ndr, rfi32rpc.dll and rfstat.dll as instructed and registered the rfcomapi.dll.

I also make sure that the Microsoft VC++ 2008, 2010 and 2012 redistributables are installed on the machine.

Using sample code that I found here (and on multiple other sites) I am getting an error.

Oh and the user that I am logged in with has a RightFax account.

This is the code block, replacing the server name, etc. with our rightfax server.   I've also changed from cpNamedPipes to TCIP without success.  It is as if it does not even see the library even though it is clearly there and registered successfully.

```
RFCOMAPILib.FaxServerClass faxserver = new RFCOMAPILib.FaxServerClass();
faxserver.ServerName = "ServerName";
faxserver.Protocol = RFCOMAPILib.CommunicationProtocolType.cpNamedPipes;
faxserver.UseNTAuthentication = RFCOMAPILib.BoolType.True;
faxserver.OpenServer();

RFCOMAPILib.Fax fax = (RFCOMAPILib.Fax) faxserver.get_CreateObject(RFCOMAPILib.CreateObjectType.coFax);

// set up your 'fax' object the way you want it, below is just some sample options
fax.ToName = "John Doe";
fax.ToFaxNumber = "4255551111";
fax.ToVoiceNumber = "4255550000";
fax.ToCompany = "ACME";
fax.FromName = "My Company";
fax.FromVoiceNumber = "4255552222";

fax.Send();
```

Here is my error:

An expression was expected after '('.
At line:1 char:71
+ rfcomapilib.faxserverclass faxserver = new rfcomapilib.faxserverclass( <<<< )

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!

Thank you

Comment: How is c++ involved?

Comment: Sorry, it may not be.  I typed C++ instead of VC++ for the redistributables and it carried that down to the tag.   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The RFCOMAPILib.dll uses an Interface "FaxServer" and an Interop Type "FaxServerClass".

Since the interop type can not be embedded, you need to use the applicable interface instead.

Replace

```
FaxServerClass faxServerClass = new FaxServerClass();
```

With

```
FaxServer faxServer = new FaxServer();
```

Additionally, be sure to close your FaxServer when you are done with it

```
try 
{ 
    //... setup fax server ...
    faxServer.OpenServer();

    //... do your stuff ...
} 
finally
{ 
    faxServer.CloseServer(); 
}
```